# Please explain Javascript image rotation code

Tags: javascript, image-rotation

I'm using the following code to create a basic image rotation feature, & I want to get a better understanding of how it's working.  I get most of it, but the line in the rotate function where it uses the 'strict' equals & the ternary operator, i.e. (i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;) is a bit confusing. I know it's incrementing the counter, but what's it doing before that?

```
var i, imgs, pic;

function rotate()
{
    pic.src = imgs[i] ;
    (i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;
    setTimeout( rotate, 2500 );
}

function init()
{
    pic = document.getElementById("pic");

    imgs = [ 'images/shimano_offer.jpg', 'images/kids_bikes1.jpg', 'images/cycle_to_work.jpg' ] ;

    var preload= new Array();
    for( i=0; i< imgs.length; i++ )
    {
        preload[ i ] = new Image();
        preload[ i ].src = imgs[ i ];
    }

    i=0;

    rotate();
}
```

Code is from http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/javascript-in-easy-steps-4th-edition/

Comment: Hi johnmc321, if one of us answered your question, could you be so kind as to click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: @AresAvatar, done, apologies for delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
(i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;
```

Could (and should) be written as:

```
if (i === (imgs.length - 1)) {
    i = 0;
} else {
    i += 1;
}
```

Yes, the former is less bytes, but much more difficult to understand and debug.

**Edit:** Norguard points out a valid way of using the ternary form for this.  I use ternaries, but in this case I would not because I would likely want to put a breakpoint on the "i = 0" condition at some point when debugging.  If you don't anticipate needing a breakpoint, his method is more compact and concise, and possibly preferable.

Comment: Ok, that structure looks more familiar. Am I right in thinking that the '- 1' refers to the last item in the imgs array?

Comment: Yes, you are.  JavaScript arrays are zero-based, like C or C++, so the first element is [0] and the last is [length -1].

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with Ares -- that's a totally valid way of reasoning the value of `i`.

The part that's confusing about that particular ternary statement (which is what it is), is that ternary is supposed to set ***ONE VALUE***.

This is an ideal case for setting a single variable.

A ternary statement that makes sense and is easy to reason about would be something like:

```
var mood = (bank_account_balance > 0) ? "happy" : "unhappy";
console.log(mood);
```

It's a very clean way of seeing that `mood` is "happy" if the balance is positive, and "unhappy" otherwise.
That's great, and concise, and didn't require a full:

```
if (....) {
    this_one_var = "one_thing";
} else if (...) {
    this_one_var = "something_else";
} else {
    this_one_var = "another_thing";
}

this_one_var = (...) ? "one_thing" : (...) ? "something_else" : "another_thing";
this_other_var = (...) ? "one_thing2" : (...) ? "something_else2" : "another_thing2";
```

Can you imagine assigning 6 different vars in the first form, instead of the second, based on different conditions?

I use the second one constantly, and it makes it very, very neat to assign values.

The problem is that in the example, they aren't doing that.
They are using the ternary as an if-statement to fire code...
...that's what an if is for.

See Ares' answer for how to do it as an if.

But as a ternary-assignment:

```
var length = imgs.length;
i = (i === length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
```

If `i` is the last index of the array, set `i` to 0, else set `i` to itself plus one.
There's no longer any crazy-logic to jump through to figure out how you got there.

Comment: +1 Norguard, your way is much better than the example the OP had.  However, keep in mind if you use a single line, it's much harder to set a breakpoint only on when i gets reset to 0, which in this case you very much might want to do.  I use ternaries, too, but never when I might want to set a breakpoint on only one of the conditions.

Comment: Absolutely.  But the function is only doing three things.  And making assignments dirt-simple goes a long way to visually-debug stuff.  Like I mentioned, if you had six variables to set in a function, which would lead to 3-deep nested-if and if-else-nested-if cases, doing ternary assignment flattens all of that out in seconds, so you're less likely to need the breakpoint there, in the first place, and you can focus on breaking on manipulation, instead.

Comment: Agreed, and I edited my answer to point out yours might be the preferable way depending on circumstances.

Comment: They're both preferable, depending on circumstance.  The benefit of having a fully-developed toolkit of useful basics.